# Akka actor handler for all messages

Tags: akka, actor

I need to add handler for all messages received by an actor (classic). If I set match(ActorBaseRequest.class) it doesn't handle particular messages, is there a way to achieve this in akka?

```
Receive operationalBehavior =
    receiveBuilder()
        //.matchAnyMessage handler
        .match(
            Start.class,
            request ->
                start())
        .match(
            Stop.class,
            request ->
                stop())
        .build();
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking for?  It's not clear if you want a decoration that will run before handling particular messages or if you want a catch-all so you don't have to specifically handle every message.

Comment: yes I want duplicate handler that will run for each message along with handlers for specific kind of messages, that will run for both start/stop commands even then have their handlers

Comment: I can think of a way to do this cleanly in Scala, but since Java doesn't really have the concept of a partial function, the best you can probably do in Java is manually inserting a call to a common function in the start/stop handlers.

Comment: can't you abstract that common logic in a function that will be called from both Start and End handlers alongside the matchAny condition?

Comment: yes, that's solution but we have lot of message handlers so it would need to be added on all places and more important it's error prone :/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of to do what (I think) you are after would be to introduce your own subclass of `AbstractBehavior` where you override `createReceiveBuilder()` to return a builder with some predefined message handling.